# What abilities grant the user AP?

Tags: final-fantasy-10-2

Some classes have special abilities that grant AP (Pray for example gives the White Mage user 1 AP every use).

Not every class has an ability that does this as far as I can tell though. So, what classes have an AP granting ability and what is that ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four ways to gain AP and are used to learn the abilities of the equipped Dressphere; Perform a special actions unique to a dressphere, use ability equipped on a garment grid, defeat enemy, and use items.

AP earned by defeating enemies (usually 1 AP standard and 2 AP for an Oversouled monster). AP is capped at 99 per battle.

The dressphere ability for Thief you can use is STEAL, for example. Basically, anything that isn't ATTACK will grant you AP for that dressphere.

Comment: I find that mildly frustrating due to my not noticing this on anybody but Black Mage, White Mage and Thief. I knew Steal worked but you only get to use it 1-4 times per battle (based on success of course)

Comment: It's a very frustrating way to level up. They took the "use the skills = level the class" idea and made it very boring. I pretty much just used 1 dressphere per character and never used the other ones.